# how to configure Model Options

Tags: cakephp, mysql-workbench

I want to reverse engineering a DB I create for the CakePHP framework.

So the naming convention is this one:

Tables are always named in plural.
If **users belongsTo or belongsToMany users**, relationships are declared like:

```
users        owners
id           
owner_id --> id
```

If **sites hasAndBelongsToMany users**, relationships are declared like

```
sites    sites_users   users
         id            
id  <--  site_id
         user_id  -->  id
```

So I would like to configure Model Options in MySQLworkbench in order to create diagram.

So I tried to set the following options but it doesn't work:

```
Column Defaults:
PK Column name: id   PK Column Type: INT
Column name: %col    Column Type: VARCHAR(45)

Foreign Key/Relationship Defaults:
FK name: %dtable%_id                            Column name: %dtable%_id
ON UPDATE: NO ACTION                            ON DELETE: NO ACTION
Associative Column name: %stable%s_%dtable%s
```

Is it the right way to do what I want?

Comment: Did you create the tables through "bake" or migrations trough "Phinx" ?

Comment: @JazzCat, I created models with bake.

Comment: Having some issues with this aswell, when im creating tables through Phinx the forgein keys are not set, that's why your relations isn't set. Mysql workbench needs forgeign keys to be set up.

Comment: @JazzCat, I understood that but I though that Model Options could give necessary infos to MySQLWorkbench in order it understand how to detect relationships.

Comment: Not sure it's possible, i'd really want to know aswell if that would work.